# Appending null value in options of select tag using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

While appending the option values to select tag, an empty option tag is also getting appended using Angular JS. I couldn't figure it out why it adds so.
Here is my JS code

```
    // Create global countries array.
    $scope.countries = [];

    countryPromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        for(index in data) {
                console.log("ID:"+data[index].id+" Name:"+data[index].name);
            $scope.countries.push({
                id:data[index].id,
                name:data[index].name                   
            });
        }
        $scope.countrylist = $scope.countries;
```

### My HTML

```
<select ng-model="country" ng-change="changeCountry()" ng-options="v.name for v in countrylist">
```

### Output of console

```
ID:1 Name:India
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model (country) is not set to a country then you will not see a selected value initially which will show as blank row when you first open the drop down, but after selecting an item that should go away. This is of course based on the assumption that your array does not have a null value.

Added an example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/65RkM/1/

```
<select ng-model="country" ng-options="c.name for c in countrylist"></select>
```

Comment: Doh! Of course, add `$scope.country = $scope.countrylist[0]` after `$scope.countrylist = $scope.countries;` to select the first country in the list by default.

Comment: @sjdaws that logic would solve the issue, but that might not be the desired business logic to apply & I updated my answer with some code to illustrate

Comment: @Brocco, in your fiddle, still the first value is null.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a blank record is being returned from your database. The simplest solution would be to check index for blanks.

```
// Create global countries array.
$scope.countries = [];

countryPromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    for(index in data) {
        if (data[index].id) {
            $scope.countries.push({
                id:data[index].id,
                name:data[index].name                   
            });
        }
    }
    $scope.countrylist = $scope.countries;
```

Comment: No. There is no blank record. Should I change anything in the html code?

Comment: Try adding an if clause to skip blank records like above, see if that fixes it. I use the exact same method as you did originally and don't get blank records so it has to be something funky. Did you try `console.log(data)` to check if there were absolutely no blank records?

Comment: No. That doesn't fix. I'm pretty sure that there is only one record and I could see in console when I print it.

Comment: Can you edit your original post with the output of `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Yeah, @Brocco was onto it, I've commented on his correct answer.